# Unicode Telugu language characters

Tags: android-development, internationalization, unicode, localization

I am developing a mobile app in android in which I  use Telugu (Indian language) texts. On my mobile Telugu language alphabets are available. Therefore, I am not facing any problem for testing my app. These characters are available in android studio also. So if I give the Unicode codes ranging from u0C00 to u0C7F in escape sequence the text in Telugu is displayed on the screen.

Now my question is - are all Unicode characters, say for example Telugu (Indian) language alphabets available on all android devices  worldwide nowadays i.e., as of January 2018 - the devices which run on android 5.0 or 6.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from v4.2, Telugu language support was made available in Android. Using Unicode you could very well develop applications that could render Telugu language for your Mobile application.